# Controller not reviving Ajax value

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I know this question has been asked many times and I am sure I'm missing something really simple but I have been stuck with this all day and have no clue why this keeps happening. My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(this).on("click",
    "#submitBtn",
    function() {
        var textValue = $('.croppedImg').attr("src");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/user/myprofile/updateavatar',
            data: textValue,
            success: function(data) {
                location.reload();
            }            
    });
    });
})
```

And the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult UpdateAvatar(string textValue)
    {
//some code
   return new JsonResult {Data = new {Status = "success"}};
    }
```

I have checked with Fiddler and the Ajax call is sending a string to the controller, but every time i try to debug it I get a null value for textValue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(this).on("click",
    "#submitBtn",
    function() {
        var textValue = $('.croppedImg').attr("src");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/user/myprofile/updateavatar',
            data: {textValue : textValue } ,
            success: function(data) {
                location.reload();
            }            
    });
    });
})
```

Comment: You dont need the `new` keyword in javascript. it will error

Comment: i tried without the new keyword it worked. Thank you very much, I can't believe I was stuck on something so stupid for a whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public virtual ActionResult UpdateAvatar(string textValue)
{
   return new JsonResult {Data = new {Status = "success"}};
}
```